# In which comic-book issues did Hal Jordan's Coast City get destroyed?

Tags: dc, superman, green-lantern

I recently read ['Emerald Twilight'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_Twilight) (Green Lantern vol. 3 #48-50)

When the story starts, Coast City is a hole in the Ground. How did that happen?

I tried to read the previous GL issues (#46-47), but they raise more questions than answers. Everyone from Superman to Green Arrow to the JLA seems to be involved.

I gather Mongul was the one who destroyed it. A net search didn't point me to any reading order or any collected trade which would explain the whole story.

Can anyone point me to the right reading order so that I know the story of the Superman vs. Mongul battle and the destruction of Coast City. I don't care how many issues it takes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was part of the [Reign of the Supermen!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman#Reign_of_the_Supermen.21) event, specifically Superman (Volume 2) #80.

[image: Superman #80]

The read order is:

- Action Comics #687
- Superman: Man of Steel #22
- Superman (Volume 2) #78
- Adventures of Superman #501
- Action Comics #688
- Superman: Man of Steel #23
- Superman (Volume 2) #79
- Adventures of Superman #502
- Action Comics #689
- Superman: Man of Steel #24
- Superman (Volume 2) #80 **<- Destruction of Coast City**
- Adventures of Superman #503
- Action Comics #690
- Superman: Man of Steel #25
- Superman (Volume 2) #81
- Adventures of Superman #504
- Action Comics #691
- Superman: Man of Steel #26
- Green Lantern (Volume 3) #46
- Superman (Volume 2) #82
- Adventures of Superman #505

But the roots of this go back further to the *Death of Superman* story, and more such as where

> Hank Henshaw

came from.

The bulk of it can be read in the collections:

- Death of Superman
- Funeral for a Friend
- Return of Superman (contains the *Reign of the Supermen!* story)

It's been reprinted a lot, there was also an omnibus which had the lot in, but that seems to be pricey and OOP on Amazon.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Can't wait to get my hands on these. +1.

Comment: You can also just read the "Superman: The Return of Superman" trade paperback.

Comment: @NikolaiDante : I remember reading those as they came out.  That summer (1993) with the Death of Superman / Funeral for a Friend / Reign of the Supermen! extended arc, combined with the Batman Knightfall saga, was a riveting time for DC fans. :-)

Comment: @praxis yes indeed :) I seem to recall "The Return of Barry Allen" over in the flash too at a similar time. Those days I couldn't wait to go comic store after school. These days.... meh.